# Determine version of Kotlin at runtime

Tags: reflection, kotlin

What can be written to determine the version of Kotlin at runtime?

```
fun main(args : Array<String>) { 
  println("v" + System.getProperty("java.version"))
}
```

prints a version, but it is the Java JDK version.  Using "kotlin.version" prints null.  Can this be done at runtime?

If the general answer is no,  is there a way to embed this information from the compile phase into a particular function or class?

Comment: There is no Kotlin version because Kotlin code is compiled to Java byte code.

Comment: Will `KotlinVersion.CURRENT` help you?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `kotlin.KotlinVersion.CURRENT`:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(KotlinVersion.CURRENT)
}
```

[Try it out here](https://play.kotlinlang.org/embed?short=dBbHnLTp_) by changing the version in the bottom-right corner of the page.

Comment: Note that `KotlinVersion.CURRENT` returns the version of the Kotlin standard library, that your code currently _runs_ with, rather than the version of the standard library or the compiler your code was _compiled_ with.